# Pokemon left in a gym

Tags: pokemon-go

I left my dragonite at a gym last week and it still hasn't been returned.  Is it a glitch?  It is a high level in a small town, but I figured it would be overthrown by now.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it still at the Gym?  It's probably earning you coins if it's been there long enough.

Answer (score 1):

A few things I would check:

In your list of Pokemon is your Dragonite's health still full?

When you visit the gym do you physically see your Dragonite pop up on the screen?

On the Store screen are you still able to collect coins/star dust from your Dragonite's presence in this gym?

If you're still able to do all of these things, then chances are he just hasn't been overthrown yet. Congrats on having a solid Pokemon!

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.  I can't remember the gym I left him in so I can't physically check.  But his health is full and i am still collecting coins/star dust.  So I'm guessing he is still in there.  His CP is 2664 so he is high, but I thought he would be back by now.  The lesson might be to not leave my top pokemons in a gym...

Comment: Yeah don't do that :P. You usually want to leave one of your strongest in a gym and use your strongest for taking gyms.

Comment: @chop: That's the lesson you're taking from this? Sounds to me like you're getting a minimum of 10 coins a day for absolutely no effort. I think the lesson you should be taking from this is making sure you visit the shop every 21 hours.

Comment: I am visiting a city this weekend and wanted to see how I do in the higher level gyms.  But I need my big boy for that...hope he comes home soon.

Comment: @chop: I'm assuming you have some other high CP Pokemon if you're rocking a 2600 Dragonite. I pretty much just use Vaporeons in the 1700-1800 CP range and take down gyms that contain Pokemon in the 2000s without much issue. Attackers have a large advantage between fielding 6 Pokemon and dodging. I suspect you'll be just fine.